# Solution succeeds within VS 2017 but fails with dotnet.exe

Tags: .net, build, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that builds correctly with VS 2017 but fails with dotnet.exe with the following error:

```
WorkerRole.cs(23,33): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'GMOK.CIL.Blog.Common' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [c:\UDLF\GMOK\CIL\BlogService\src\Service\Processor\Processor.WorkerRole\Processor.WorkerRole.csproj]
WorkerRole.cs(38,53): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'TollBlock' does not exist in the namespace 'GMOK.CIL.Blog.Processor.Plugins.megaData' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [c:\UDLF\GMOK\CIL\BlogService\src\Service\Processor\Processor.WorkerRole\Processor.WorkerRole.csproj]
Done Building Project "c:\UDLF\GMOK\CIL\BlogService\src\Service\Processor\Processor.WorkerRole\Processor.WorkerRole.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

This solution have several projects and some of them have dependencies upon each other. I suspect that the issue is due to incorrect build order but i don't see an option to specify the build order or it might be some other issue.

Anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: `dotnet build` can only handle .NET Core SDK based projects. Are you sure that all projects under this solution satisfy that?

Comment: I think the error you presented is due to an error in another project. Another project received an error and did not compile, so you got the current error. Check for additional errors in the output, and let us know.